# Extract words only with R

Tags: r

I have strings like these:

```
x <-c("DATE TODAY d. 011 + e. 0030 + r. 1061","Now or never d. 003 + e. 011 + g. 021", "Long term is long time (e. 104 to d. 10110)","Time is everything (1012) - /1072, 091A/")
```

Desired output:

```
d <- c("DATE TODAY","Now or never","Long term is long time","Time is everything")
```

After an hour with SO search, I just could not do it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The pattern is not very clear.  For example, `to` is not considered in the 3rd string.  I assume that it is inside the braces.?

Comment: The problem here is what do you define a word. In your second string you have `to`, how would you tell the regex engine it's not a word?

Comment: You could try `sapply(str_extract_all(x, perl('(?<=[0-9] )[A-Za-z]+(*SKIP)(*F)|[A-Za-z]{2,}')), paste, collapse=" ")`

Comment: @akrun That should be an answer.

Comment: What about one-letter words - "a" or "I"? Or words with apostrophes or dashes - "don't" or "hyper-space"?

Comment: yes, dashes etc. I had to remove or replace before using your solution. So its not elegant. But does the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bit uses `stringr` to extract anything containing two or more alphabeticals:

```
> library(stringr)
> unlist(lapply(str_extract_all(x,"[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]+"),paste,collapse=" "))
[1] "DATE TODAY"                "Now or never"             
[3] "Long term is long time to" "Time is everything"
```

I'm hoping the "to" missing from your desired output is a mistake on your part. Its a perfectly good word, and you said you wanted to extract words.

Comment: Did seem a bit easy... I suppose the alternative is the string up to the first word that doesn't match the regexp in my code...

Comment: You can simplify your regular expression to `'[a-zA-Z]{2,}'`

Comment: @KonradRudolph Been using R for years, and never knew that form. What's a good place to learn more advanced Regexp from?

Comment: @Serban Generally, http://www.regular-expressions.info/. The webdesign is hurting my eyes but it’s really a rather good resource.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern is not very clear.  But, based on the example showed, here are a couple of ways to get the expected result.

```
sub('( .\\.| \\().*', '', x)
#[1] "DATE TODAY"             "Now or never"           "Long term is long time"
#[4] "Time is everything"
```

or

```
 pat1 <- '(?<=[0-9] )[A-Za-z]+(*SKIP)(*F)|[A-Za-z]{2,}'
 sapply(regmatches(x,gregexpr(pat1, x, perl=TRUE)), paste, collapse=" ")
#[1] "DATE TODAY"             "Now or never"           "Long term is long time"
#[4] "Time is everything"
```

If `to` is a valid word and the expected result had a `typo`

```
 pat1 <- '[A-Za-z]{2,}'
 sapply(regmatches(x,gregexpr(pat1, x, perl=TRUE)), paste, collapse=" ")
 #[1] "DATE TODAY"                "Now or never"             
 #[3] "Long term is long time to" "Time is everything"
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the others that "to" is a valid word.  Here's a `stringi` approach

```
library(stringi)

stri_replace_all_regex(x, "\\s?[A-Za-z]?[+[:punct:]0-9]", "")
# [1] "DATE TODAY"                "Now or never"             
# [3] "Long term is long time to" "Time is everything"
```